# Sorting and pagination with Javascript

Tags: javascript, eclipse-ditto

I use your Javascript binding (@eclipse-ditto/ditto-javascript-client-dom) for HTTP access to Ditto.

```
load5ThingsAsc() {
    var options = DefaultSearchOptions.getInstance().withLimit(0,5);
    options = options.withSort("+thingId");
    const p = this.searchHandle.search(options).then(result => console.log("returned",result.items))
  }
```

does fire a:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/2/search/things?option=limit(0%2C5)%2Csort(%252BthingId)
```

this results to a Error 400 with the message "Invalid input '%', expected Asc or Desc". A

```
...
options = options.withSort("-thingId");
...
```

works fine.

What's my mistake

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in the JS client. Please feel free to create a [GitHub issue in our ditto-clients project](https://github.com/eclipse/ditto-clients/issues/new) for that - or even better: Provide a PullRequest fixing the issue ;)

Comment: created a report: https://github.com/eclipse/ditto-clients/issues/157.